# AngularJs ui-sref not working, and state abstracts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

For some reason my ui-sref links are not updating and allowing me to change state on my app.

Can someone please tell me what i have done wrong?  I have attached a plunkr link for the full code

```
App.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    'use strict';

    // defaults to home
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    // states
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'app.html',
            controller: 'AppController'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl:'home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .state('app.settings', {
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsController'
    });

}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/m77wrOU0sMLG0fmicTaK

If i navigate to /home, this works and if i go to /settings that also works.  but the links are not generated on my pages?

Also, if i want to have multiple layouts, say i would like an admin layout and a normal user layout, maybe the admin layout would hide a few items on the page and show others, would this be best to be done using routing?  I have about 6 different parts of the page, currently not setup as views, but i wonder if this is the route i should go down?

Is there anything wrong with having more than 1 abstract state in your stateProvider, or is that stupid?

Comment: ui-sref isn't working because you aren't using the "angular" way of putting in the html. Instead of element.html(html), you should just provide the html as the `template` part of your directive object in  navbar.js.  I can't answer the other questions right now so that is why I didn't want to use this as the answer. Here is a plunker with a working ui-sref: http://plnkr.co/edit/eFr20zmCRY3dLf7s9SNL?p=preview